# Running an azure devops pipeline multiple times at the same time with different variables values

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am automating a task using selenium using azure devops pipelines and I would like to run the same pipeline/task multiple times at the same time with different values.

So far I am still making my research as I don't understand the process yet.

From what I read and understood is that this has to do with the "jobs" or "agents".

Comment: Something like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#multi-job-configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve for this you'd have two ADO jobs with the same task and different inputs being passed in. The ADO jobs, by default, will run in parallel. Each job will be dispatched to a separate agent. Thus you will need to have [multiple agents available for the jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=ms-hosted).